# Create PermissionTabSetting and PermissionSetApplicationVisibility

Tags: apex, permission-sets

I had some issue importing Permission Sets in Managed package:

- I can not import User Settings
- I can not update Permission Sets from Managed Package in `post install script`

So I decided to generate `PermissionSet`, `ObjectPermissions` and `FieldPermissions` in script and I am now facing a new issue. Those set also need information below:

```
<applicationVisibilities>
    <application>My App</application>
    <visible>true</visible>
</applicationVisibilities>

<tabSettings>
    <tab>MyTabWithComponent</tab>
    <visibility>Visible</visibility>
</tabSettings>
<tabSettings>
    <tab>MyOtherTabWithComponent</tab>
    <visibility>Visible</visibility>
</tabSettings>
<tabSettings>
    <tab>MyCustomObject__c</tab>
    <visibility>Visible</visibility>
</tabSettings>
```

But I can not create `PermissionTabSetting` or `PermissionSetApplicationVisibility` in Apex. Any workaround ?